# Confused about how the assignment operator works

Tags: python, python-2.7

There is something about the way python assigns a value to a variable that I'm not fully comprehending. Why is it that this:

```
charlie = ['d', 'o', 'p', 'e']
beth = charlie
beth[0] = charlie[1]
print charlie
```

gives me this:

```
['o', 'o', 'p', 'e']
```

As far as I understand the assignment operator only works one way, thus this code should only change the first index of beth, not charlie. So what gives?

Comment: This looks fine to me, what is your expectation?

Comment: This should help clear up the confusion: http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables

Comment: Also, read [this section](http://www.nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html#h_assignment) of Ned Batchelder's Facts and Myths about Python Names and Values. You might as well read the whole thing, really.

Comment: `beth = charlie` does not create a copy, just 2 names for the same thing.

Comment: note `charlie is beth` will evaluate to `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `beth = charlie`, `beth` is now an alias of `charlie`. That means that anything that happens to `beth` now happens to `charlie`.

http://gestaltrevision.be/wiki/python/aliases

In order for this not to happen, you can try `beth = list(charlie)` or `beth = charlie[:]`.

Comment: if you want for beth to be a new list, you can do beth = list(charlie), these will now be different objects.

Comment: or `beth = charlie[:]`

Answer (score 0):

You just assigned the same list to two variables, so `charlie` and `beth` are the same object.